# What to do if I can't tell if it's unsalvagable without an edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I've come across posts that look pretty terrible in Triage, but *look* like they have enough information to be answerable, and potentially slightly useful questions.

Unfortunately, due to formatting and grammar errors (among other things) I can't really tell. I could flag them as "unclear what you're asking" because it is unclear, but they aren't necessarily unsalvagable - I just can't tell before trying to salvage it. Is there a better option than flagging, or opening it in another window to edit first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can always Skip...

No, really - if you're not sure, Skip - let someone else take a crack at it.

I was gonna follow that up with more detailed guidance, but then I realized I'd be making it all up - I just Skip these. Skip. Skip. Skip until you find one you know at a glance where it should go.

<sup><sub>Flies in the buttermilk...</sub></sup>